# using Keras' flow_from_directory with FCNN

Tags: python, keras, data-augmentation

I trained a constitutional neural net for image segmentation with Keras successfully. Now I am trying to improve performance applying some data augmentation to my images. To do so I use the `ImageDataGenerator` and then `flow_from_directory` to load only batches into memory (I tried without but I get memory error). Code example is:

```
training_images = np.array(training_images) 
training_masks = np.array(training_masks)[:, :, :, 0].reshape(len(training_masks), 400, 400, 1)

# generators for data augmentation -------
seed = 1
generator_x = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=True,
    featurewise_std_normalization=True,
    rotation_range=180,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode='reflect')

generator_y = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=False,
    featurewise_std_normalization=False,
    rotation_range=180,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode='reflect')

generator_x.fit(training_images, augment=True, seed=seed)
generator_y.fit(training_masks, augment=True, seed=seed)


image_generator = generator_x.flow_from_directory(
    'data',
    target_size=(400, 400),
    class_mode=None,
    seed=seed)

mask_generator = generator_y.flow_from_directory(
    'masks',
    target_size=(400, 400),
    class_mode=None,
    seed=seed)

train_generator = zip(image_generator, mask_generator)
model = unet(img_rows, img_cols)
model.fit_generator(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=int(len(training_images)/4), epochs=1)
```

However when I run the code I get the following error (I am using Tensorflow back-end):

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Incompatible shapes: [14400000] vs. [4800000]
     [[Node: loss/out_loss/mul = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](loss/out_loss/Reshape, loss/out_loss/Reshape_1)]]
```

In the error it complains about incompatible shapes 14400000 (400x400x9) vs. 4800000 (400x400x3). I am using a custom loss function here (and if you look at the error it says something about the loss) that is the Dice coefficient, defined as follows:

```
y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
intersection = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
return (2. * intersection + 1.) / (K.sum(y_true_f) + K.sum(y_pred_f) + 1.)
```

Here I use (400,400,3) images with masks for 1 class of shape (400,400,1). My NN has inputs defined as `Input((img_rows, img_cols, 3))` and output as `Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid', name='out')(conv9)` (but this was working fine when training without data augmentation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because you're reading the masks in RGB color mode.

The default `color_mode` in `flow_from_directory` is `'rgb'`. So without specifying `color_mode`, your masks are loaded into `(batch_size, 400, 400, 3)` arrays. That's why `y_true_f` is 3 times larger than `y_pred_f` in your error message.

To read the masks in grayscale, use `color_mode='grayscale'`:

```
mask_generator = generator_y.flow_from_directory(
    'masks',
    target_size=(400, 400),
    class_mode=None,
    color_mode='grayscale',
    seed=seed)
```

Comment: that was it, I must have missed the argument in the documentation!